# Wordpress ACF Repeater sub fields

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am having an issue in Wordpress with ACF Repeater sub-fields link object not returning href on front-end. Basically the link in the front-end does not output any links set in WP admin. Text output is working.

Repeater fields:

```
Field label = Link to doc
Field name = link_to_doc
Field type = Repeater
```

Repeater sub-fields 1:

```
Field label = Link
Field name = link
Field type = Link
```

Repeater sub-fields 2:

```
Field label = Text of link
Field name = text_of_link
Field type = Text
```

PHP code:

```
<?php if ($section['link_to_doc']) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($section['link_to_doc'] as $link) : ?>
       <div>
       <a href="<?= $link['link'] ?>" class="btn-txt">
       <?= $link['text_of_link'] ?>
      </a>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Could anyone check the php code and let me know what's wrong?

Comment: In your if statement you are not checking anything. Try saying "if(isset($section['link_to_doc'])" or check if it's not empty. You can also "var_dump" your $section array to see if it's set.

Comment: Also, ACF does not return arrays, it returns objects, so to access that you'll need to say $section->link_of_text

Answer (score 0):

This topic has no answer for a while, you've probably found a solution. But now ACF is explaining how to access the data for nested repeaters directly in the documentation.

```
<?php
// Loop over the first repeater
if( have_rows('type') ):
    while( have_rows('type') ) : the_row();

        // Loop over sub repeater rows.
        if( have_rows('type') ):
            while( have_rows('type') ) : the_row();

                // Get sub value.
                $child_title = get_sub_field('name');

            endwhile;
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

There is also other ways to access this kind of data, here's the list:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/